# How to visualize progress on github forked repos?

Tags: github

I will be very specific.  I am wanting to see if any of the forks of https://github.com/BackMarket/github-mermaid-extension may have updated to a newer version of mermaid js, but when I click https://github.com/BackMarket/github-mermaid-extension/network/members I only see a flat network...no ahead/behind indicator or date of last update.  Is there a way to discover which of these projects, if any, have been making changes?  Presently I have to click each project and manually inspect the change history, e.g. "This branch is even with BackMarket:master."

Comment: There is a branch with mermaid 8.4.8: https://github.com/BackMarket/github-mermaid-extension/commits/greenkeeper/mermaid-8.4.8 The network graph you are looking for is there: https://github.com/BackMarket/github-mermaid-extension/network

Comment: True...I found it by looking at the pull requests and did a local build to install it for chrome (it works) but how to quickly discover that?  Is it possible?  I guess that network graph may include non-pull requests? YES IT DOES...THANK YOU!

Comment: You click "Insights > Network" for the network graph, and for the branches you click on "X Branches", both from the repos start page.